# change the Foreground color of emonic in C# editor

Tags: c#, eclipse-plugin

I would like to change the Foreground color of emonic(eclipse plugin) C# editor, 
syntax are working fine
[image]

beside syntax, C# editor preference said that some preferences may be set on the Text Editors preference page.
[image]

which I did..
[image]

Text Editors looking good
[image]

not so good in C# editor..
[image]

I tried to modify files in my workspace
.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings\org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs
.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings\org.emonic.base.prefs

still, these moves were in vain.. 
any advice would be appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: I am not familiar with the C# editor itself, but most work the same way for syntax coloring : either they have hardcoded the foreground color, or they inherit from another editor. All colors and fonts are not available through the *General > editors > Text Editors* preference page. You might also want to take a look at the colors in *General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts*. For example, the Java editors takes its colors from there...

Comment: @Kellindil thanks for the info, I tried everything in Colors and Fonts, it still wont do.. :( wish there's newer plugin than emonic for editing C# file, since I don't find other plugin for editing unity's script files..